# Replacing multiple dependant nested async calls in Javascript (ECMA 6)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, ecmascript-6, async-await

I am initializing my JS application by calling a number of methods asynchronously loading ressources, each of them depending of the previous ones. My intuitive solution is to nest the calls in callback functions (cba, cbb, cbc, cbd), beeing called from the inner of LoadA, LoadB, LoadC, LoadD respectively after these (LoadA, LoadB, LoadC, LoadD) were successfully completed:

```
app.LoadA( function cba() {
        app.LoadB( function cbb() {
            ....        
            app.LoadC( function cbc() {
            ...           
                app.LoadD( function cbd() {
                    ...
                } );
            } );
        } );
    } );

LoadA( cb )
{
    let url = '.........'; // just an url
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    let lh = this;

    req.onload = function ol(event)         
    {
        let arrayBuffer = req.response; 
        let loadedObject = Convert( arrayBuffer, ......... );
        cb( loadedObject ); // call, if successed!
    }
    req.send(null);
}
....
```

LoadA returns without loading the object, so LoadB has to wait until LoadA's embedded onload function calls the callback cb and so on.

I don't like this nesting solution, as it is hard to overview and to maintain.

**My question is: is there an other (focused on the "happy path", nicer, shorter, less confusing, easier to understand and maintain) possibility to achieve the same result?**

Comment: I _promise_ there's a better way of doing this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

Comment: This is what is called a callback hell... Try searching for solutions to callback hell

Comment: Promises look to me like writing more confusing, lengthy and unmaintainable code... or is there a short way to use them with my example?

Comment: You can use async await, it better to read

Comment: You should make your example more concrete, with actual values you want to return or accumulate, etc. Then the answer can be more to the point.

Comment: @Trantor the above code would be like `app.LoadA.then(app.LoadB).then(app.LoadC).then(app.LoadD).then(...)`. Is that really more confusing?

Comment: @Andy _then_ you better _await_ a reply from the OP. (sorry, that took me faaar too long)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for your _deferred_ response.

Comment: @Andy No problem. I hope it helped _resolve_ the issue.

Comment: @Andy, your exchange with evolutionxbox is most entertaining. Yes, I have enjoyed watching. I would definitely describe this conversation as _observable_. [cringes & puts down the shoe-horn]

Comment: @MartinJoiner I hope the conversation left you feeling _fulfilled_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid callback hell, you'll need to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

If the `loadA, ..., loadN` functions return promises then you just call `.then()` after each one in order.

```
loadA().then(function() {
  loadB().then(function() {
    loadC().then(...
  });
});
```

What's now important is to remember that `.then()` return a Promise that resolves with the value of it's argument.

So if both `loadA` and `loadB` return Promises, you can just chain them like so:

```
loadA().then(function() {
  return loadB();
).then(...)
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
loadA().then(loadB).then(loadC).then(...)
```

Much simpler!

If your function *doesn't* return a Promise, then you need to wrap them inside one with a helper function.

```
function wrapInsidePromise(f) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    f(function() {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

var pLoadA = wrapInsidePromise(app.loadA);
var pLoadB = wrapInsidePromise(app.loadB);
...

pLoadA().then(pLoadB).then(...);
```

What's more, in ES6 you can use `async/await` which let's you use Promises in an *asynchronous* way.

```
async function() {
  await loadA();
  await loadB();
  ...
  let finalResult = await loadN();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, the final async function looks really nice, but I need the load calls in a special sequence ... (a,b,c,d...)

Comment: @Trantor what do you mean? With `await` those asynchronous calls will get called _in this exact sequence_, one after the other.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to invoke most of the promise-returning functions in your snippets.

Comment: Also, that's *not* how the [`Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) works [for promisification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi oops! Thanks!! I've edited my answer, I suppose it's now correct...?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a comparison of "callback hell" and the nicer code you can achieve with `async/await`:

```js
// dummy implementations: 
//  these functions call cb with value 1 to 4, after 100ms
const loadA = (cb) => setTimeout(_ => cb(1), 100);
const loadB = (cb) => setTimeout(_ => cb(2), 100);
const loadC = (cb) => setTimeout(_ => cb(3), 100);
const loadD = (cb) => setTimeout(_ => cb(4), 100);

function callbackHell() {
    loadA( function cba(a) {
        loadB( function cbb(b) {
            loadC( function cbc(c) {
                loadD( function cbd(d) {
                    console.log([a, b, c, d]);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

async function nicerCode() {
    const res = [
        await new Promise(loadA),
        await new Promise(loadB),
        await new Promise(loadC),
        await new Promise(loadD)
    ];
    console.log(res);
}

callbackHell();
nicerCode();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It's good for demonstration purposes, but IRL it's a bad idea to promisify callbacks just by passing them to Promise constructor because of error handling.

Comment: @estus, of course, for error handling, the callback version of the function could accept an error callback function. The way functions can be promisified depends of course on their signature. With the given signature in the question, it could be done like this. Exceptions occurring in those functions should be captured with a `.catch` method. But mentioning all the ins and outs of using promises correctly is going well beyond the scope of the question in my opinion.

Comment: I'm thankful for any helpful suggestion :-) . But are you sure loadA will be called BEFORE loadB (and so on) in your solution ?

Comment: Yes, that is what `await` does. It stops the function from execution further until the promised value becomes available. At that time the function's state is restored, and execution continues with the next statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would break this up using a "Promise" for each async call.

MDN have a great explanation of how to use them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Your app code could end up looking something like this...

```
app = {

    loadA: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            console.log('Loading A');
            resolve();
        });
    },

    loadB: function () {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            console.log('Loading B');
            resolve();
        });
    },

    // For demonstration, I have coded loadC with a rejection if it fails
    // (Success is based on a random boolean) 
    loadC: function () {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('Loading C');
            var success = Math.random() >= 0.5;
            if( success ){
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject('C did not load');
            }

        });
    },

    loadD: function () {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            console.log('Loading D');
            resolve();
        });
    }

};

// A global function for reporting errors
function logError(error) {
    // Record the error somehow
    console.log(error);
}
```

Now call them in a promise chain

```
app.loadA().then(app.loadB).then(app.loadC, logError).then(app.loadD);
```

Now, if in the future you decide to change the order you want your functions called, you don't need to touch the code in the functions at all because you used promises. You can just change the line containing the promise chain:

```
app.loadA().then(app.loadD).then(app.loadB).then(app.loadC, logError);
```

*(The above example assumes you can change the methods on app to work as promises. If app is a 3rd party thing that you cannot edit the solution would be different)*

Comment: Promises look to me like writing more confusing, lengthy and unmaintainable code... or is there a short way to use them with my example?

Comment: Hold on. Do you want to write short code, maintainable code or ECMA 6? Your question suggests you want to jump in with all the shiny new ECMA 6 stuff, but your comments are rejecting everyone suggesting promises (a very ECMA 6 thing). And now you want maintainable code but also short code? Often, to make code more maintainable you write it in a longer way (modulated).

Comment: While I totally agree on using promises, this is not what it should look like. This is still nesting everything (but using the flattening-by-function-declaration technique), a promise chain should look like `loadA().then(loadB).then(loadC).then(loadD)`.

Comment: @Bergi Feel free to edit my answer to make my snippet better. I personally would like to improve my understanding of Promises so I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that looks much better now. You might even want to provide the complete bodies of the promise creations, calling into the callback-based `app` methods

Comment: @Bergi Yes I would like to do that. I am just hacking out a solution in a test file before I edit my answer again :-)

Comment: @Bergi What do you think now?

Comment: Just edited my question to clarify the behaviour of LoadA (B,C,D) : LoadA returns without loading the object, so LoadB has to wait until LoadA's embedded onload function calls the callback cb and so on. Do you think your solution would still fit?